# JAXB class declaration for the below xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Not able to convert the forms node to object

I am not able to unmarshall the forms node in the below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <start>
        <action>
            <application>
                <name>sarat</name>
            </application>
            <forms>
                <form>
                    <name>flexMobile</name>
                    <type>flex</type>
                    <channel>mobile</channel>
                </form>
                <form>
                    <name>flexMobile1</name>
                    <type>flex1</type>
                    <channel>mobile1</channel>
                </form>
            </forms>
        </action>
    </start>
```

Appreciate if there are any pointers on the forms and form node conversion to object

Start.js

```
package com.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 

@XmlRootElement
public class Start {
    Action action;

    @XmlElement
    public Action getAction(){
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(Action action){
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

Action.js

```
package com.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Action {
    private Application application;
    private List<Form> forms;

    public Action(){}
    public Action(Application application, List<Form> forms){
        super();
        this.application = application;
        this.forms = forms;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Application getApplication(){
        return this.application;
    }
    public void setApplication(Application application){
        this.application = application;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<Form> getForms(){
        return forms;
    }
    public void setForms(List<Form> forms){
        this.forms = forms;
    }
}
```

Application.js

```
package com.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Application {
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Forms.js

```
package com.jaxb;

import java.util.List; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Forms {
    private List<Form> form;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Form> getForm(){
        return form;
    }
    public void setForms(List<Form> form){
        this.form = form;
    }
}
```

Form.js

```
package com.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Form {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String channel;

    private Form(){}
    private Form(String name, String type, String channel){
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getChannel(){
        return channel;
    }
    public void setChannel(String channel){
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}
```

I am not able to structure the Forms class to convert the xml into object, appreciate if there are any suggestions

Parser.js

```
package com.jaxb;

import java.io.File;  
import java.util.List;  
import javax.xml.bind.*;  

public class Parse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        try {  

            File file = new File("data.xml");  
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Start.class);  

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
            Start que= (Start) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  


            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(que, System.out);    
        } catch (JAXBException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

    }  
}
```

Comment: When you populate your object model and marshal it out what does the resulting XML look like?

Comment: Updated Action.java, below is the output when marshalling
 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<start>
    <action>
        <application>
            <name>sarat</name>
        </application>
        <forms/>
    </action>
</start>

Comment: Is that the result of marshalling a fully populated object model or marshalling the object that was unmarshalled?

Answer (score 0):

There is mismatch between your xml and the classes.
The xml suggest that you would have Object Forms which holds list of Form elements.
Your java model, has Form elements directly under Action. 
So unmarshaller expects xml like this:

```
<action>
            <application>
                <name>sarat</name>
            </application>

                <forms>
                    <name>flexMobile</name>
                    <type>flex</type>
                    <channel>mobile</channel>
                </forms>
                <forms>
                    <name>flexMobile1</name>
                    <type>flex1</type>
                    <channel>mobile1</channel>
                </forms>

        </action>
```

If you start with xml, generate a xsd schema (there web pages that can do it for you) and use it to generate jaxb classes. That way you will avoid this kind of mistakes

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, actually the code worked when i added the name="forms" for element attribute

Answer (score 0):

In forms.js, after adding the name value the code worked

```
package com.jaxb;
import java.util.List; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
public class Forms {
    private List<Form> form;
    @XmlElement(name="forms)
    public List<Form> getForm(){
        return form;
    }
    public void setForms(List<Form> form){
        this.form = form;
    }
}
```